# GdkPixbuf Linux dependencies

Tags: python, screenshot, gdkpixbuf

**GdkPixBuf.pixbuf_get_from_window()** does not work on my **Linux Manjaro (Cinnamon)** machine. The code below (only the screenshot part) did work perfectly to grab a screenshot in my old **Manjaro** installation, but recently I reinstalled, and now the same code does not work. I even tried the same code in **Linux Mint (Cinnamon)** but it didn't work there either.

No exceptions occur in the code when I run/debug it with Visual Studio Code, nothing in **.xsession-errors** and nothing sticks out in the **journalctl** log.

So I can only guess that some dependency is missing on my new machine that I had installed on my old machine, but without an error message it is hard to find out what is missing. I get no output when I run the application from the terminal. The application works fine, except the screenshot part.

I have installed **PyGObject** and **PyCairo** in my virtual environment of course. So there must be another dependecy that I am missing, anyone know what is missing?

[Edit] I don't know if this is a problem with my virtual environment (somehing that I need to `pip install`) or if it something that is missing on my machine (something that I need to `sudo pacman -S`). When I had it working on my old machine, I had really just learned about virtual environments and python (still a newbie though), so it might have been working because of something I had installed globally.

```
from gi.repository import Gdk, GdkPixbuf

class ScreenShotHelper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Setup the screenshothelper class"""
        # Get root window (contains all monitors and windows)
        self.root_window = Gdk.get_default_root_window()

    def grab_and_scale(self, position, size, requested_size):
        """Grab a screenshot and scale it down to requested size"""
        # Get specific area from root window
        pb = Gdk.pixbuf_get_from_window(self.root_window,
                                        position.left,
                                        position.top,
                                        size.width,
                                        size.height)
        # Scale the image down to the size the user asked for
        pb = pb.scale_simple(requested_size.width,
                             requested_size.height,
                             GdkPixbuf.InterpType.NEAREST)

        return pb
```